# client_id undefinded on grant_type=password (oauth2orize)

Tags: node.js, oauth2orize

I am creating an API in nodejs with oauth2orize and passport, but when I ask for the token, the client_id parameter is undefined.

Oauth2orize:

```
server.exchange(oauth2orize.exchange.password(function (client, username, password, scope, callback) {
    console.log(client);    // This is undefined
```

Post:

```
grant_type: password,
client: id_client,    // I tried with client_id, clientId, id...
username: username,
password: password
```

Why is the client parameter is undefined?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create at least one Passport Strategy like this :

```
var passport = require('passport'),
    ClientPasswordStrategy = require('passport-oauth2-client-password').Strategy ;

passport.use("clientPassword", new ClientPasswordStrategy(
    function (clientId, clientSecret, done) {
        Clients.findOne({clientId: clientId}, function (err, client) {
            if (err) return done(err)
            if (!client) return done(null, false)
            if (!client.trustedClient) return done(null, false)

            if (client.clientSecret == clientSecret) return done(null, client)
            else return done(null, false)
        });
    }
));
```

Then you need to bind your route so that your request will pass threw this Strategy : (with express)

```
app.post('/url', passport.authenticate('clientPassword'), server.token());
```

Finally, to request your token, the POST parameters must be :

- client_id
- client_secret
- username
- password
- grant_type : password